# Finitely additive set function with bounded variation but not countably additive.

Tags: measure-theory

Can anyone give me an example of a measurable space ($\Sigma$, $F$) on which we can define a finitely additive set function which is not countably additive but for which the total variation is bounded?

Here the variation of $\mu$ (a finitely additive set function) is defined by $|\mu|(\Sigma)$ where for any $A$ in $F$ we have

$|\mu|(A)=sup(\sum_{k=1}^{n} |{\mu(A_k)}|:A_k \ form \ a \ measurable \ partition \ of \ A)$.

Comment: Any finitely additive but not countably additive probability measure is like that. E.g., try $\Sigma = \mathbb{N}$, $F = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mu$ a non principal ultrafilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a simpler approach: Let $\lambda$ be a bounded linear functional on $\ell^\infty$ such that $$\lambda x=\lim x_j$$_if_ the limit exists (Hahn-Banach) and $||\lambda||=1$.

If $0\le x\le 1$ then $||1/2-x||\le1/2$, hence $|1/2-\lambda x|\le1/2$, hence $\lambda x\ge0$. So $\lambda$ is positive. For $E\subset\Bbb N$ define $$\mu(E)=\lambda\chi_E.$$

Then $\mu$ is finitely additive since $\lambda$ is linear. Not countably additive since $\mu(\{n\})=0$ while $\mu(\Bbb N)=1$.

And finitely additive plus positive implies bounded variation (that other example was not finitely additive): Say $(E_j)$ is a partition of $\Bbb N$. For every $n$ there exists $F_n$ so $E_1,\dots,E_n,F_n$ is a partition of $\Bbb N$. So $$\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(E_j)+\mu(F_n)=\mu(\Bbb N)=1,$$hence $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu(E_j)\le 1.$$

Comment: I don't think that has bounded variation.

Comment: What's the definition of "bounded variation" here? (There are at least two equivalent versions for real measures which are not equivalent without countable additivity...)

Comment: Ah sorry, yes I'll add it in the above.

Comment: Gotta go, will check back later...

Comment: Ok, try this one.

Comment: Ah nice one! From a quick read it looks like it works. Interesting that the example uses $l^{\infty}$, the motivation for the question was connected to characterising the dual of $L_{\infty}(\Sigma,F)$.

Comment: Presumably you've got that the dual of $L^\infty$ is in fact the space of finitely additive complex measures...

Comment: Yep. I was hunting for a member of the dual space that was finitely linear but not countably in some sense - exactly like the above.